# How to update an existing Form using Form Builder in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, orbeon

I have recently updated my version of Orbeon from 4.3 to 4.4. Some MySQL issues has been solved in this version. Now I can save forms, and the summary list page show all of them. The problem became when I want to update a form.

In my case, I open the form, add some options, and press the "save" button again, but an error is showed:

`There was an error communicating with the database. Please contact the application administrator.`

If I look at the log file, the real error is:

`Duplicate entry '144f5752fdf7c0a13bed72f8126449f98278d6d1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

It seems that the "save" button is not doing an update, only an insert. But when using "existDB" it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I see that the [MySQL script](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/persistence/relational/ddl/mysql-4_4.sql) for creating the database structure does not include any primary key. If we remove the PK, now I can save the form, and the "summary list" only shows the last change.